# I want to get Id of primary table but get null and Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here is my controller code. Can someone help me? how can i get primary table id. I have primary table with one id and secondary table called articles in which all fields are shown here in controller code how can i get id of primary table(the relationship is primary and foreign key relationship)

```html
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $article = new Article;

        $article->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $article->content =  $request->content;
        $article->live = (boolean)$request->live;
        $article->post_on = $request->post_on;
        dd($article->user_id);
        $article->save();

    // Article::create($request->all());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is this primary table? Is it a table that is related to this one? Where should this id come from?

Comment: This is users table where primary key is id and its come from that primary table(i have primary table is users and secondary table is articles in which user_id is foreign key). I have user model which relate to primary table users.

Comment: Have you tried to `dd(Auth::user())`? and what did you get?

Comment: its give me null

Comment: Try `auth()->user()` instead. You may be using the wrong class or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an inverse relationship e.g. `belongsTo` in your `Article` model which attributes that article to your `User` model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

See the **Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship** section.

Then you can do something like `$article->user->id`.

**If your relationships are already defined, use `$article->fresh('user')` after the `save()` method.**

Comment: Problem Solved:: You must be logged in to get user id that was the problem. The Auth::user()->id will return user id when you are logged in. Otherwise it will show error trying to get property of non object or null return.